# Updating to couchbase lite 2.0.0 causing cannot resolve symbol errors

Tags: android, build.gradle, couchbase-lite

I am trying to update from couchbase.lite 1.4.0 to 2.0.0, but when I update and sync my build.gradle file I seem keep getting 'cannot resolve symbol' errors for my imports (AndroidContext, Document, and Database). After looking at the [dcoumentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/couchbase-lite/java.html), it appears that all I have change change is:

```
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0'
```

unless I missed something else...

Here is my complete build.grade file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-forestdb:1.4.1'
}
```

Comment: That's all you need for pulling the community version. What does your top level grade file look like - Where you specify the repositories?

Comment: Just to do a sanity check...2.0 has breaking changes to the API so you will need to rework your application to use that.  It's not just as simple as changing the dependency from 1.4 to 2.0.  Also you should remove the ForestDB entry as it has no bearing on 2.0 and could possibly interfere.

Comment: @borrrden can you give me more detail about your comment actully i facing the same issue.

Comment: It means you cannot use the same code in 1.x and 2.x.  The API is different.  Check the API docs for more info about how to use 2.x.